# How to track checkboxes with Django and endless pagination?

Tags: forms, checkbox, django-endless-pagination

I am a Django noob and have a situation that goes beyond the basic documentation, etc.

I am updating an ordering webpage that has a form structured as follows:

- several text boxes, etc to gather general info (name, date, etc)
- two separate tables for selecting (via checkbox) catalogs that are generated/managed using endless_pagination.  Each table can have thousands of records, hence the endless_pagination.  The first column in each table is a checkbox with value = catalog.id.
- a textbox where the user can manually enter catalog IDs
- a submit button

I am not sure how to keep track of what a user has selected in the two paginated tables since the checked boxes are lost when choosing a different page.  Also, when the user flips back and forth between the pages, the previoulsy checked catalogs will need to be re-checked(since the checked state is not maintained).  I am also not sure which tool(s) to use to deal with this.

My thought is to use JavaScript (with which I have minimal experience) to update a list of catalog IDs whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked and:
 - and attach that list to the form or
 - update a variable in the form or 
 - send as a variable separate from the form, whichever is possible/makes more sense.

I'm hoping that maintaining a list of catalog IDs is possible because the next iteration of this form will likely include some sort of filtering so I'm trying to devise a solution that will not have to be reworked later.

I have reviewed a lot of posts but I believe the closest solutions are rendered useless because of the endless_pagination.

Let me know if further clarification is required.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

UPDATE

I tried using JavaScript to store the catalog IDs in an array when a checkbox is checked.  This does not work when a user selects another page in the pagination.  The array of checked catalog IDs is lost when the page 'reloads'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into this problem right now as well. I'm handling this by writing the checked items to localStorage so they carry across to page 2, 3, etc.. as well as show up as already checked when you go back to page 1. Then every time the page loads, either find and check the existing checkbox, or create a hidden input with the appropriate name and value and append it to the main form.

```
var selected_items = []

function add_item_to_checkbox(item) {
    localStorage.setItem('selected_items', JSON.stringify(selected_items));
checkbox.on("click", add_item_to_checkbox);
```

bahh... Just look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmdp6q51/) it's easier to read and yeah. I don't have to type JS into a textarea on stackoverflow.

Here is my [javascript minus a few things that are specific to my code](http://jsfiddle.net/zmdp6q51/). I'm sure it could be improved upon but it works really well for my application.